# I am looking for triplets of synonyms?

Tags: etymology, synonyms

I am looking for triplets of synonyms or words which were close in meaning in the past, but changed their meaning.

So, I want a pivot word, such that one word in the triplet used to mean that pivot word, and another word in the triplet *now* is now close to the pivot word.

An example of such a triplet would be car, machine, and computer. Car and machine used to be similar in meaning, but now machine is often used to refer to a computer.

Comment: I don't think *car* ever meant machine:  [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=car&searchmode=none) c.1300, "**car**: wheeled vehicle," from Anglo-French carre, Old North French carre, from Vulgar Latin *carra, related to Latin carrum, carrus (plural carra), originally "two-wheeled Celtic war chariot," from Gaulish karros, a Celtic word (compare Old Irish and Welsh carr "cart, wagon," Breton karr "chariot"), from PIE *krsos, from root *kers- "to run" (see current (adj.)).

Comment: I thought you were looking for things like: "keen, cool, bad"

Comment: Your example is *species, genus, species*. There are millions of them. Your criterion of *close* is too vague. Can you refine this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a triplet:  oleaginous, greasy, oily